# ¿Por qué las plantillas deben declararse en la cabecera?

Tags: c++

¿Alguien me quisiera explicar porque cuando hago una clase y defino plantilla normalmente tengo que dejar el cpp en blanco para que funcione correctamente y definir e implementar todo en el .h o header?

Comment: @Trauma la cuenta tienes que ponerla tu para que te haga el ingreso correspondiente

Comment: @eferion No hombre, los bancos ya automatizan eso. Yo le paso el cargo a su cuenta, y tu verás como no hay problema. Bueno, yo no, PaperBirdMaster :-)

Comment: @Trauma Dedicándote a lo que te dedicas no deberías confiar tanto en ellos :P

Comment: @eferion ¡¡ HAHAHAHAHA !! También es verdad ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Las plantillas C++ pueden ser declaradas, definidas o instanciadas:

- **Declaración**: Se indica que la plantilla existe sin detallar cómo es; el nombre de la plantilla podrá usarse siempre que no provoque la creación de una instancia. En otras palabras: describe la plantilla sin entrar en detalles.
  [image]
- **Definición**: Se describe la plantilla al detalle, cuenta como declaración si no había declaración previa, puede instanciarse la plantilla sin limitaciones.
  [image]
- **Instanciación**: Cuando se indican (o se deducen) los parámetros de la plantilla. En otras palabras: Cuando se crea lo que corresponda con las características solicitadas.
  [image]

---

Las plantillas se instancian en cada uso, por lo que cada uso **necesita** la definición. Si declaramos la plantilla en un archivo de cabecera (hpp) y la definimos en un archivo de código (cpp), cuando se instancie la plantilla el compilador no encontrará la definición (por estar en un lugar inaccesible) y el código no podrá ser compilado<sup>1</sup>.

---

1. Este complejo problema tiene su raíz en el propio lenguaje C++ y la manera en que se genera el código, pero se está trabajando en alternativas en futuros estándares (módulos C++20).