# Templates dentro de el archivo hpp y cpp en metodos de clases

Tags: c++, poo, template

tengo un problema con los templates en c++, tengo un metodo que los usa y lo declaro en su archivo `.hpp` pero dentro de la logica de la funcion igual declaro el template pero me manda error.

```cpp
// entity.hpp
class Entity {
    public:
        // Start a empty Entity (without transform component)
        Entity(unsigned int id);

        // Manage the component entry and exist of the entity
        void removeComponent ();

        template<typename ComponentType, typename ... ComponentArguments>
        void addComponent (ComponentArguments&& ... componentArguments );

        // Call the base component functions each frame
        void start ();
        void update();

    private:
        // List of component of the Entity
        std::vector<Component*> components;
};
```

```cpp
// entity.cpp
template<typename ComponentType, typename ... ComponentArguments>
void Entity::addComponent (ComponentArguments&& ... componentArguments) {
    // Create the new component without specific type passing his arguments (fancy c++ code) and append his owner
    ComponentType *newComponent(new ComponentType(std::forward<ComponentArguments>(componentArguments)...));

    // Add the new component to the component list and mask
    components.emplace_back(newComponent);
}
```

El error es este, la verdad no entiendo muy bien que pasa

```
PS C:\Users\josem\Documents\game_engine> make
g++ ./src/main.cpp ./src/ECS/entity.cpp -I ./includes -L ./lib -Wall -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -o game.exe -O2
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\josem\AppData\Local\Temp\cckj8wGD.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1e): undefined reference to `void Entity::addComponent<Position>()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

No sé que tengo que cambiar para que funcione, cuando tengo todo en el archivo `.hpp` funciona, pero me gustaría tener todo en 2 archivos (aunque no estoy seguro si esa la buena práctica, si no lo es háganmelo saber por favor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es la forma en que funcionan los templates.

Un template solo existe en el código fuente.

Recién cuando usas el template, el compilador genera el código correspondiente y una vez compilado existe como un conjunto de instrucciones.

---

Puedes solucionarlo, de algunas maneras.

- Poniendo todo el código de la clase o función que use un template en el mismo archivo (.h). Si prefieres, puedes escribir el código en un archivo .cpp y agregar un `#include` con dicho archivo.

  Por ejemplo:

  ```
  // foo.h
  template<typename T>
  void foo();

  #include "foo.cpp"

  // foo.cpp
  #include "foo.h"
  #include <iostream>

  template <int N>
  void foo(){
      std::cout << N << "\n";
  }

  // main.cpp
  #include "foo.h"

  int main(){
      foo<1>();
      foo<2>();
  }
  ```

  Nota que así las funciones `foo` no están en una unidad de traducción adicional. Por lo tanto no debes compilar el archivo .cpp directamente.
- Teniendo las definiciones en el archivo .como puedes generar las especializaciones explícitamente.

  Por ejemplo:

  ```
  // foo.h
  template<typename T>
  void foo();

  // foo.cpp
  #include "foo.h"
  #include <iostream>

  template <int N>
  void foo(){
      std::cout << N << "\n";
  }

  template void foo<1>();
  template void foo<2>();

  // main.cpp
  #include "foo.h"

  int main(){
      foo<1>();
      foo<2>();
  }
  ```

  En este caso las funciones `foo` sí están en otra unidad de traducción.

  Si no puedes modificar el archivo .cpp, puedes crear uno nuevo en el que incluyas el otro y escribas las especializaciones. Así:

  ```
  // foo.cpp
  #include "foo.h"
  #include <iostream>

  template <int N>
  void foo(){
      std::cout << N << "\n";
  }

  // foo-impl.cpp
  #include "foo.cpp"

  template void foo<1>();
  template void foo<2>();
  ```

Las funciones `foo` también se encuentran en una unidad de traducción diferente pero deberías compilar el archivo con las especializaciones en lugar del original. Sino obtendrás errores de símbolos duplicados.

[Más información](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl).

Comment: Que complejo jajaja, muchas gracias el documento que adjuntaste abajo me ayudo mucho

Answer (score 3):

El comportamiento que describes se da por la combinación las siguientes características de la compilación de código [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

- Los "*niveles de existencia*" de los objetos.
- Los archivos de cabecera **no se compilan**.
- Las plantillas se instancian *inline*.

Vamos punto por punto.

#### Niveles de existencia.

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) un objeto puede estar conceptualmente en tres "*niveles de existencia*": declarado, definido o instanciado. Pero el caso de las plantillas es especial; antes de explicar por qué voy a describir los conceptos que he mencionado.

- **Declaración**: Se indica que la plantilla existe sin detallar cómo es; el nombre de la plantilla podrá usarse siempre que no provoque la creación de una instancia. En otras palabras, nos describe la plantilla sin entrar en detalles:

  [image]
- **Definición**: Se describe la plantilla al detalle, cuenta como declaración si no había declaración previa, puede instanciarse la plantilla sin limitaciones. Es decir, nos detalla la plantilla al completo:

  [image]
- **Instanciación**: Cuando se indican (o se deducen) los parámetros de la plantilla. En otras palabras, crea lo que corresponda con las características indicadas:

  [image]

#### Las cabeceras **no se compilan**.

En general los archivos de cabecera (`*.hpp`) se usan para declaraciones y los archivos de código (`*.cpp`) se usan para definiciones. Si le pides a un compilador que compile un archivo de cabecera no generará código.

A un nivel más técnico un archivo de código es una [unidad de traducción](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit) la cual se genera combinando todas las definiciones con todas las declaraciones las cuales llegan al archivo de código mediante la cláusula `#include`.

#### Las plantillas se instancian *inline*.

Normalmente un objeto C++ se instancia así:

```
tipo_t obj; // Instanciamos un objeto llamado 'obj' de tipo 'tipo_t' .
```

Pero una plantilla no puede instanciarse así, ya que necesita saber cuáles son sus parámetros de palntilla:

```
template <typename T>
struct plantilla {};

plantilla p;         // ¡Error!
plantilla<int> pi;   // Correcto, es una plantilla sobre 'int'.
plantilla<short> ps; // Correcto, es una plantilla sobre 'short'.
```

Nos encontramos el caso de que una plantilla no se instancia hasta que se le proveen los parámetros de plantilla, también podemos ver que una misma declaración de plantilla puede dar lugar a múltiples definiciones las cuales sólo son conocidas en el momento de instanciar: en la misma línea en que se instancian... es decir *inline*.

---

Ahora que hemos repasado eso ¿Qué está pasando con las plantillas separadas en archivos de cabecera y código? Veamos un sencillo ejemplo:

###### `f.hpp`

```
template <typename T>
void f(const T &); // Declaración
```

###### `f.cpp`

```
#include "f.hpp"

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f(const T &t) // Definición
{
    std::cout << t;
}
```

###### `main.cpp`

```
#include "f.hpp"

int main()
{
    f(0); // ¡Error! No tenemos el cuerpo de f<int>()
    return 0;
}
```

Cuando se crea la unidad de traducción de `main`, se compila el resultado de pasar el preprocesador por el archivo `main.cpp`, que podría tener este aspecto:

```
template <typename T>
void f(const T &); // Declaración

int main()
{
    f(0); // ¡Error! No tenemos el cuerpo de f<int>()
    return 0;
}
```

En `main` estamos instanciando la plantilla `f(const T &)` como `f(const int &)` así que busca el cuerpo de `f(const int &)` pero no lo encuentra y da error.

Si hubiese sido una función normal (no una función plantilla) la definición de la función estaría en una unidad de traducción que se habría compilado y el enlazador la habría encontrado. Pero al ser una función plantilla el compilador no ha compilado nada ya que en el archivo de código (`*.cpp`) no le hemos dicho qué instancia debe compilarse (las plantillas se instancian *inline*) ¡eso sólo se ha dicho en `main.cpp`!

Las posibles soluciones son:

- No separes el código de plantilla en archivos cabecera y código.

  ###### `f.hpp`

  ```
  #include <iostream>

  template <typename T>
  void f(const T &t) // Declaración y definición
  {
       std::cout << t;
  }
  ```
- Incluye el archivo de código de la plantilla (no hace falta que se llame `*.cpp` puede tener una extensión arbitraria).

  ###### `main.cpp`

  ```
  #include "f.hpp"
  #include "f.cpp"

  int main()
  {
       f(0); // Correcto, encontramos el cuerpo de f<int> al incluir "f.cpp"
       return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Estoy casi seguro de haber visto esas imágenes en otra respuesta tuya. ¿Será que esta pregunta se puede considerar un duplicado?

Comment: @Mateo esas imágenes (y parte de la respuesta) las he sacado de unas diapositivas que hice sobre las plantillas C++, también las he usado en [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/257932/2742) y [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/346184/2742) respuesta que siendo puristas, podrían considerarse duplicados.