# Cómo crear librería dinámica con plantillas

Tags: c++, linux, template

Estoy probando para crear una librería dinámica. Para ello tengo el siguiente proyecto original:

```
|->main.cpp
|__->include/calculadora.h
|__->src/calculadora.cpp
```

**man.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "calculadora.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a = 10;
    float b = 5;
    cout<<sumar(a,b)<<endl;
    cout<<restar(a,b)<<endl;
    cout<<multiplicar(a,b)<<endl;
    cout<<dividir(a,b)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**calculadora.h**

```
#ifndef CALCULADORA_H
#define CALCULADORA_H

int sumar (int a, int b);
int restar (int a, int b);
int multiplicar (int a, int b);
int dividir (int a, int b);

#endif // CALCULADORA_H
```

calculadora.cpp

```
#include "calculadora.h"

int sumar(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int restar(int a, int b)
{
    return a-b;
}

int multiplicar(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}

int dividir(int a, int b)
{
    if (b==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return a/b;
}
```

Esto me permite crear una librería dinámica. Dentro de ./src:

```
g++ -shared -o libcalculeitor.so calculadora.cpp
```

Y funciona.
Ahora quiero pasarlo a plantillas.
Una vez pasadas todas las funciones a plantillas, veo que es incapaz de compilar, puesto que no encuentra las funciones. Entonces recuerdo que con plantillas no se pueden separar las funciones del contenido, así que lo paso todo al fichero **calculadora.h:**

```
#ifndef CALCULADORA_H
#define CALCULADORA_H
template<typename T>
T sumar(T a, T b)
{
    return a+b;
}

template<typename T>
T restar(T a, T b)
{
    return a-b;
}

template<typename T>
T multiplicar(T a, T b)
{
    return a*b;
}

template<typename T>
T dividir(T a, T b)
{
    if (b==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return a/b;
}

#endif // CALCULADORA_H
```

El programa compila, pero yo quiero hacer una librería dinámica con las funciones.

Pruebo de nuevo. Dentro del directorio include:

```
g++ -shared -o libcalculeitor.so calculadora.h
```

Aquí ya veo dos cosas "raras".

1.- La librería ha pasado de tener pocos kb a 1.9 mb

2.- Esto es más subjetivo, pero en la consola (linux) no me aparece en letras verdes, como corresponde a las *.so sino en blanco.

Ahora intento compilar el ejecutable:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -o calculeitor main.cpp  -lcalculeitor -L./include/libcalculeitor.so
```

Y me saltan los errores:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:10:11: error: ‘sumar’ was not declared in this scope
   10 |     cout<<sumar(a,b)<<endl;
      |           ^~~~~
main.cpp:11:11: error: ‘restar’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘register’?
   11 |     cout<<restar(a,b)<<endl;
      |           ^~~~~~
      |           register
main.cpp:12:11: error: ‘multiplicar’ was not declared in this scope
   12 |     cout<<multiplicar(a,b)<<endl;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:13:11: error: ‘dividir’ was not declared in this scope
   13 |     cout<<dividir(a,b)<<endl;
      |           ^~~~~~~
```

Y aquí me he quedado. Entonces, ¿cómo he de hacer para crear una librería dinámica con plantillas?

**Edito:**

Aclaración. Cuando quiero crear el ejecutable con plantillas eliminé el include a "calculadora.h" de main.cpp. Lo hice porque si ahora el fichero calculadora.h tiene todas las funciones incluidas y no sólo las definiciones, éstas se incorporarán (pienso) al ejecutable y se pierde el sentido de la librería dinámica. No obstante pruebo a incluir "calucladora.h" y tengo este error (una vez que he copiado la libería en /usr/local/lib/:

```
/usr/local/lib/libcalculeitor.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Luego ya tengo claro que la supuesta libería dinámica de 1.9 mb no era correcta, como pensaba.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Templates dentro de el archivo hpp y cpp en metodos de clases](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/562707/templates-dentro-de-el-archivo-hpp-y-cpp-en-metodos-de-clases)

Comment: Simplemente no puedes exportar plantillas en un DLL. Nunca forman parte del ejecutable final. Lo que sí forma parte de él son las especializaciones. Tal vez sería posible compilar estas en una librería.

Comment: @Mateo. Efectivamente. Mi planteamiento de origen era inviable, y todo lo demás sobraba. Digamos que no tiene sentido lo que planteo. Este enlace es esclarecedor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022623/c-shared-library-with-templates-undefined-symbols-error